# Using 3rd party libraries in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, curses, pdcurses

Recently, I have started using MS Visual Studio 2013. However, I have not been able to use a 3rd party library, particularly PDcurses. When I follow the usual advice to "go to linker, add the lib in input. Then put the path in general", no errors disappear. I still receive the "Cannot open include file: 'curses.h': No such file or directory" error. My guess for why this does not work is because it is for an older version. Also, I have tried to find the solution on MSDN with no luck.

How do I go about using the library?

Files included with the library: curses.h, panel.h, pdcurses.dll, pdcurses.lib.

Comment: Your problem is not with the linker, it is with the compiler. Change the compiler options so that you add the path to the header files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found what the issue is, and I'll be posting it here for posterity:

Go to property pages. It is necessary to go to the C/C++ category under configuration properties and add the path to "Additional Include Directories", **not** "Additional Library Directories" under Linker. (Not sure if both are required or only the first).

Comment: Both would be required -- "Include" to find curses.h, during the compilation stage, and "Library" to find pdcurses.lib, during the linking stage.